# Ошибка работы Python приложения NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020635115A00>: Failed to establish

Tags: python, pyinstaller, localhost, eel

Всем привет, прошу помощи специалистов

Собрал свое первое приложение на Python с WEB интерфейсом Eel, затем скомпелировал в .exe файл при помощи Pyinstaller. На моем устройстве на Windows 10 все работает отлично, никаких проблем. Но на других компютерах, тоже Windows 10, вылазит следующая ошибка при попытке отправить запрос на Localhost

**ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение**

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и какие есть варианты решения?

**Полный текст ошибки из консоли:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
  File "urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
  File "urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
  File "urllib3\connection.py", line 234, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1255, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 950, in send
  File "urllib3\connection.py", line 200, in connect
  File "urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020635115A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=35000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/profile (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020635115A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 281, in _process_message
  File "main.py", line 80, in get_data
  File "main.py", line 167, in update_profile
  File "main.py", line 143, in create_profile
  File "requests\api.py", line 119, in post
  File "requests\api.py", line 61, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=35000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/profile (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020635115A00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
```

**Код функции, в которой возникает ошибка**

```
def create_profile(acc_id):
    
    url = "http://localhost:35000/api/v2/profile"

    body = {"name": "Profile" + acc_id,
            "browser": "mimic",
            "os": "win"
    }
    header = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    r = requests.post(url, json.dumps(body), headers=header)
    
    print(r)
    print(r.status_code)
    uuid = json.loads(r.content).get("uuid")
    print("Аккаунт №", acc_id, uuid)
    return uuid
```

Comment: на другой машине по адресу http://localhost:35000 есть работающий сервер?

Comment: Точно не могу сказать. Есть программа Indigo, в которой я определил 35000 порт для работы. После запуска программы, в теории она должна являтся сервером, на который мое приложение отправляет запрос. На момент теста на другом компе, программа была запущена